# cambiar una funcion javascript a jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

hola como podria cambiar una funcion javascript a jquery?
esta es la función que quiero cambiar

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // add padding top to show content behind navbar
  navbar_height = 
   document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
  document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px';
  });
```

lo he intentado con esta función, pero aun desconozco como hacerlo

```
 jQuery.ready(function(){
 navbar_height = 
  document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight;
 document.body.style.paddingTop = navbar_height + 'px';
 });
```

este es el menu que tengo pegado arriba pero me oculta los elementos de la pagina por eso quiero agregar esa funcion

```
    <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar fixed-top   navbar-expand- 
   md 
   navbar-dark bg-primary" aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">

   <h2 id="main-nav-label" class="screen-reader-text">
    <?php esc_html_e( 'Main Navigation', 'understrap' ); ?>
   </h2>


  <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container ); ?>">
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[sidemenu]'); ?>

        <?php
      wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location'  => 'primary',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
            'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav justify-content- 
           flex-start px-4',
            'fallback_cb'     => '',
            'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
            'depth'           => 2,
            'walker'          => new 
     Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
        )
    );
    ?>

    </div><!-- .container(-fluid) -->

    </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál sería la necesidad real de agregar JQuery? De todas formas, lo que has intentado ¿no funciona? ¿Te da algún error?

Comment: estoy trabajando con una nav de bootstrap 5 en wordpress, no me funciona solamente, voy a dejar el codigo de mi nav, lo que quiero es que tenga una padding del mismo tamaño del nav, para que no me oculte los elementos al usar la clase fixed-top de boostrap

Comment: Bootstrap 5 suprimió de su código base el uso de JQuery, existe una buena razón para ello. ¿Estás seguro que **necesitas** JQuery para lo que tratas de hacer?